# Current flowing in a circuit made up of ideal conducting wires

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors

Taking a simple circuit with a battery to provide a potential difference and some resistance across, also our circuit is made up of an ideal conducting material so $\sigma$ is infinity. Now I have read in electrodynamics, that the current density $J$ is equal to $\sigma$ times electric field $E$. And since $\sigma$ is infinite, $E = J/\sigma =0$ for the wire which is an ideal conductor and thus even in electrodynamics, all the charges are on the surface of the wire. My doubt is, the surface of the conductor  should too be equipotential but then how are charges flowing in the first place then through the circuit?  And from where did we get the current density then if there can be no charge flowing?

Answer (score 0):

In a conducting wire , the surface is not equipotential . There is a very minute potential difference between an elemental part of conducting wire which along with the infinitesimal resistance of the conducting wire gives you a finite value of current through any conducting wire connected by a potential source .

Comment: Oh okay, two doubts: 1) The minute potential difference is because not every conductor is ideal, right? And 2) That means in a conducting wire all the charges are flowing on the surface and there is still no net charge inside. Correct?

Comment: Reading your comment I think you consider a conducting to be charged , however a conducting wire is never charged by an external agent . Its electrically neutral , it has holes and electrons in it which are driven in a particular direction due to an applied voltage across battery terminal . The charge which resides on a conductor is the external charge given to it . Moreover , Gauss law is applicable only in a static state of charges and not in a dynamic flow of charges as in your case . So I feel you got answer to 2) There are charges flowing inside a conducting wire not on its surface

Comment: Answering 1) That minute potential difference is due to the source you applied , as electrons started their flow inside the wire . If you somehow maintain zero potential difference between 2 points ( as in a Wheatstone brigde ) the current will never flow in a wire ( having resistance ) joining those 2 points . If in the previous case tne wire joining the 2 equipotential points had zero resistance ( ideal ) the current flowing in it would be indeterminate .